# Why does jquery DataTables turn my zeroes into floats with values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am trying to display some JSON data in a jQuery datatable with a precision of two decimal places. It seems to work... sometimes. In the pic below, Chrome's dev toolbar renders the value as 2000.0000000 but the datatable displays $2.000020000200002e+58. I used the following number renderer, as per the docs (https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers):

```
<table id="budgets" class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Jan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#budgets').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
    data: data,
    scrollY: 400,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            orderable: false,
            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(null, null, 2, '$'),
            targets: [0],
        }
    ], 
    columns: [
        { data: "months[0].value" }
    ]
});
```

});

[image: Picture of Chrome's dev tools showing the wrong number]

Here's the data:

```
    var data = [{"months":[{"month":1,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":2,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":3,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":4,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":5,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":6,"value":0,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":7,"value":3849.8300000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":8,"value":-753.7700000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":9,"value":2185.6300000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":10,"value":-1141.4300000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":11,"value":151.5400000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":12,"value":-4291.8000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0}]},{"months":[{"month":1,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":2,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":3,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":4,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":5,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":6,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":7,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":8,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":9,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":10,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":11,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":12,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0}]},{"months":[{"month":1,"value":3688.6800000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":2,"value":1064.6300000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":3,"value":-424.8400000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":4,"value":-505.3100000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":5,"value":-98.3000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":6,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":7,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":8,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":9,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":10,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":11,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":12,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0}]},{"months":[{"month":1,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":2,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":3,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":4,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":5,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":6,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":7,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":8,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":9,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":10,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":11,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0},{"month":12,"value":2000.0000000000000000,"canEdit":false,"occupancy":0,"total":0}]}]
```

Comment: Please may you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, just a moment.

Comment: Woah, 2e+58 is about 55 orders of magintude out! That is a huge number. I don't think that's the renderer. Something else is going on here. Have you double checked the numbers in the data?

Comment: Please note, you don't need all those zeros after the decimal

Comment: They're coming from the source system. I don't want them.

Comment: I noticed that it works if I replace the months array in the Json with explicit month properties like Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. For some reason datatables can't handle an array index reference in the columns.